# localhost declaration on PC?

Tags: localhost, window, hosts

I was wondering , where does windows declares  that `localhost` is -  the machine itself   (where is it configured?) ?

It is not in the hosts file.

I thought it is in the Registry but I couldn't find it there by searching.

As you can see , it does ping :

[image]

And hosts doesnt contain this definition

[image]

Comment: It's the hosts file....

Comment: The actual definition used is defined within the DNS service itself. It does not depend on an external definition.

Comment: @Crippledsmurf 1. The NSLookup doesn't return any results for Localhost, hence this doesn't come from the DNS serer. 2. If you disable the DNSCache service (which disables both the hosts file and the DNS cache), you can still ping Localhost and receive the same results. That doesn't add up.

Comment: @EliadTech so where from comes this setting ?

Comment: @Ramhound dont you see the remarks ?

Comment: You asked where it was defined for windows so I told you.  Its not defined in the registry thats for sure

Comment: @ramhound you said it's the host file . It is not . Because as you can see it is remarked

Comment: Not the DNS server, the DNS service. This is a Windows system component which handles resolution of names. The name "localhost" is mapped directly to 127.0.0.1 somewhere within this component, as alluded to by the remarks in the hosts file itself

Comment: This is precisely why the mapping is done internally and isn't (to my knowledge) configurable

Comment: @Ramhound if you look in the hosts file the line `# 127.0.0.1       localhost`  is commented with the #.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Windows DNS service is the system component responsible for resolving DNS names. The name `localhost` is mapped to the IPv4 address `127.0.0.1` and the IPv6 address `::1`  within the DNS service, as part of it's code, rather than via any external source.

This is explicitly stated in the Windows hosts file:

> localhost name resolution is handled within DNS itself.